# Splitting values in a particular cell into rows in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to manipulate a data frame into the output data frame format. There are multiple values in a particular cell separated by ','. When I use `.stack()` to convert a number of values to rows, the remaining empty cells are filled with `NaN`. Is there any generic solution in `pandas` to handle this?

**Input data frame:**

```
   x1     y1        x2           x3          x4
   abc    x or y    v1,v2,v3     l1,l2,l3    self
   abc    z         no1,no2,no3  e1,e2,e3    self
```

**Output data frame:**

```
   x1    y1    x2     x3     x4
   abc   x     v1     l1     self
               v2     l2 
               v3     l3
         y     v1     l1     self
               v2     l2
               v3     l3
   abc   z     no1    e1     self
               no2    e2
               no3    e3
```

Comment: Try `df.set_index(df.index).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(",").apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index(drop=True).fillna("")`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.set_index(df.index).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(",").apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index(drop=True).fillna("")
```

Output:

```
    x1    x2   x3    x4
0  abc    v1   11  self
1         v2   12      
2         v3   13      
3  abc   no1   e1  self
4        no2   e2      
5        no3   e3
```